# WordPress Custom Page Theme showing posts of current user

Tags: php, wordpress

After implementing the code it doesn't show all the posts but the one of one specific user. However this is not the user who is logged-in but always the same user.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
<?php 
// the query
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
    $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array($author_query)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php echo get_the_date(); ?><?php echo the_author(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where is the catch i don't get?

Comment: can you explain these 2 lines `$author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array($author_query));`?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to this topic so i was trying code brackets from different explanations to see if i can make it working i do not have any deeper insights about that line of code

Comment: there are multiple lines not one 2 lines, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one wp_query object that accepts a simple array

```
$wpb_all_query =  new WP_Query($author_query);
```